# Is it possible to retrieve the HTTP Status Response Code in an MVC View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to retrieve the HTTP Status Response Code in an ASP.net MVC View?

For instance, I can get the server name with @Environment.MachineName.

Is there a similar, easy way to get the http status response code for the current page?

If not, what about using Javascript?

If not, is there any way to do it without issuing a new request?  I want to grab this information off of every page view, and I'd rather not double the hits just to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Why you want the current page http status code?

Comment: @Kousha I want to run some javascript to record some data on the page load, but I only want to run it on a 200.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
Context.Response.StatusCode
```

Comment: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.HttpContext.Response.get'

Comment: I'm sure he meant `HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode`

Comment: @CulturalMishap: Sorry; that should have been `Context`.  (or, for that matter, simply `Response`).

Comment: Is there a difference between `Response.StatusCode`, `Context.Response.StatusCode`, and `HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode`?

Comment: @hunter: No; they will all reference the same `HttpContext`.  Look at the helper properties of your page base type.

Answer (score 4):

`Response.StatusCode` is on the `WebPageRenderingBase`

So you can write this on any view:

```
@{ Response.StatusCode }
```

---

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagerenderingbase(v=vs.111).aspx